# Leverage browser caching, how on apache or .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, browser-cache

What to do here? I have a huge list of files that Google Speed Page said to "Leverage Browser Caching".. but I don't know how? Do I mess or change the Apache config file (below) or do I put something in my .htaccess page?

```
 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyRequests Off
        CacheRoot "/var/run/proxy"
        CacheSize 1024
        CacheGcInterval 24
    #CacheMaxExpire 24
    #CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
    #CacheDefaultExpire 1
    #NoCache a_domain.com another_domain.edu joes.garage_sale.com
        <Directory "disabled_proxy">
            Allow from example.com
            Deny from all
            Order Deny,Allow
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
    ##
    #### mod_expires is configured so that all static files but images
    #### expire after 60 seconds. Any response that has a life span of more
    #### than 5 seconds (see webperfcache.conf) will be cached by webperfcache.
    #### Make sure your CGIs return a "Cache-Control: no-cache" header if you
    #### elect to make your dynamically generated HTML pages not cache-able.
    #### If all your HTML pages are static you may also increase ExpiresDefault.

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault A60
        ExpiresByType image/bmp A3600
        ExpiresByType image/gif A3600
        ExpiresByType image/ief A3600
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg A3600
        ExpiresByType image/png A3600
        ExpiresByType image/tiff A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-cmu-raster A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-portable-anymap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-portable-bitmap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-portable-graymap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-portable-pixmap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-rgb  A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-xbitmap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-xpixmap A3600
        ExpiresByType image/x-xwindowdump A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/basic A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/midi A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A3600
        ExpiresByType audio/x-wav A3600
        ExpiresByType video/mpeg A3600
        ExpiresByType video/quicktime A3600
        ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo A3600
        ExpiresByType video/x-sgi-movie A3600
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was doing the same thing a couple days ago.  Added this to my .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A86400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
#
<FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

And now when I run google speed page, leverage browwer caching is no longer a high priority.

Hope this helps.

Comment: check your code, i got an internal server error using your code

Comment: @Francesco check your server, did you enable mod_headers.c and mod_expires.c ?

Comment: I have a problem like that in CakePHP but this is not a solution for all files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927604/leverage-browser-caching-and-cakephp

Comment: @Adam - For ex: I set ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year" it means till one year all my site JPG will load from cache , right? But if I change any JPG file then will it reflect as new in my site? or it will load old image till 1 year from cache?

Comment: @HelpingHands .. yes, that is correct.  You would want to use "access plus 1 year", you can also add more settings to "Header set Cache-Control" for more control over caching/expiring.

Answer (score 102):

I took my chance to provide full `.htaccess` code to pass on Google PageSpeed Insight:

1. **Enable compression**
2. **Leverage browser caching**

> ```
> # Enable Compression
> <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
>   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
> </IfModule>
> <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
>   mod_gzip_on Yes
>   mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
>   mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
>   mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
>   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
>   mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
>   mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
>   mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
> </IfModule>
>
> # Leverage Browser Caching
> <IfModule mod_expires.c>
>   ExpiresActive On
>   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
>   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
>   ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
>   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
>   ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
>   ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
>   ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
>   ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
>   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
>   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
>   ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
> </IfModule>
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>   <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
>   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
>   </filesmatch>
>   <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
>   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
>   </filesmatch>
>   <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
>   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
>   </filesmatch>
>   <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
>   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
>   </filesmatch>
> </IfModule>
> ```

There is also some configurations for various web servers see [*here*](https://github.com/hyipscript/server-configs).
Hope this would help to get the 100/100 score.

[image: optimized page score]

Comment: I thought mod_headers and mod_expires do the same thing with different options and only one one should be used. am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing @hyip

Comment: gtmetrix still shows me to enable gzip compression using your code. For me this works `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript`.

Comment: I thought that 100/100 is a myth! :) Congrats for that. Many scripts like opencart or woocommerce have problems with the ExpiresDefault configuration. any idea on this one?

Comment: Any `ExpiresDefault` can be overridden by a Header set Expires. Observe `.htaccess` hierarchy to make sure that your `ExpiresDefault` isn't being overridden at a lower level

Answer (score 38):

This is what I use to control headers/caching, I'm not an Apache pro, so let me know if there is room for improvement, but I know that this has been working well on all of my sites for some time now.

### **Mod_expires**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

This module controls the setting of the Expires HTTP header and the max-age directive of the Cache-Control HTTP header in server responses. The expiration date can set to be relative to either the time the source file was last modified, or to the time of the client access.

These HTTP headers are an instruction to the client about the document's validity and persistence. If cached, the document may be fetched from the cache rather than from the source until this time has passed. After that, the cache copy is considered "expired" and invalid, and a new copy must be obtained from the source.

```
# BEGIN Expires
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expires
```

### **Mod_headers**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

This module provides directives to control and modify HTTP request and response headers. Headers can be merged, replaced or removed.

```
# BEGIN Caching
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Caching
```

Comment: Don't forget to enable mod_headers and mod_expires, you can do so by running *a2enmod rewrite*    and   *a2enmod headers*  commands

Comment: Why did you include double-slash in the regexes (`\\.`…)? It would be correct to use only one, e.g. `<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">` (example copied verbatim from the [FilesMatch docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch).

Comment: Im not sure why I did @QuinnComendant, thanks for catching that, I have updated the post to reflect the proper syntax. Seems to work just fine with both but always best practice to have proper syntax.

Answer (score 8):

First we need to check if we have enabled mod_headers.c and mod_expires.c.

```
sudo apache2 -l
```

If we don't have it, we need to enable them

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Then we need to restart apache

```
sudo apache2 restart
```

At last, add the rules on .htaccess (seen on other answers), for example

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A86400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
#
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: <FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch mayt be wrong show error 500