# Wordpress admin login gives me blank page back

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

Hi all I am having this problem with Wordpress admin login and W3 Total Caching.

Lets start from the beginning. When I visit the website it appears to be working just fine.
When I try to login on the Wordpress admin page it returns me a blank page. No errors nothing just a blank page.

This is not the first time it happens, so I called my hostings provider to check if anything is going on with the servers. So we solved the problem last time by just rebooting the server. That worked website was running again and could login in to wp admin area.

Now today same thing happens again. We did some research my hostings provider comes up with this error from wordpress.

`mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3559.`

I have no idea what this problem is and where it comes from.

Probably this is not the only problem with this site. We are also using W3 Total Caching for this site. Are there any issue's know with this plug-in that can make the server do strange things?

Kind regards

Comment: I see from your other questions that you're having other server-related problems. What hosting company are you using? Are you using Apache? If so, instead of using server caching that's likely using your server's resources, you should try using a .htaccess file that enables browser caching. An example of what I'm talking about can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878427/leverage-browser-caching-how-on-apache-or-htaccess). Confirm that mod_expires is enabled on your Apache instillation before attempting this.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will definitely let them look in to this!

Comment: You're welcome. I believe [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about) would be a better place that Stack Overflow if you find yourself with more server-related issues. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

is definitely the way to go.

We had recently removed a cacheing plugin but it had left behind some pieces of code in wp-settings that needed removing.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the wp-login page is blank means there's a code error somewhere (probably in a recently added/updated plugin). If you can, FTP onto your server, go to `wp-content/plugins/`, rename a directory that holds the contents of a plugin, then refresh your login page.

Once it loads, the directory you've just renamed is the one causing problems. Rename all of the other plugin directories to what they were previously, and either find an  alternative plugin, or attempt to fix the plugin yourself if you know PHP.

Comment: Well ok yes assuming that there is a problem with a plugin ok. But can you explain to me then why everything works properly after a server reboot? It suggests that there is not a problem with a plugin, at least not with the code. 

Maybe also worth mentioning, when I enable debug mode in wordpress config. It gives me back errors on almost every plugin is installed. I assume this is not OK even in debug mode.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't WordPress then. You should discuss your Apache instillation with your hosting company immediately. The settings within apache.conf are likely too high. Go through it and refer to [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html) for information on what the directives actually do. You should start with MaxRequestsPerChild.

Answer (score 0):

The blank page means there's a server error, check the error logs, or add the following line to your wp-config.php file to get them to show on screen.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

That will show you the errors so you can start debugging.

Comment: Yes I know we have a lot of errors when the page doesn't work. However like I mention in my post, when we restart the server everything works fine also with debug on!

Answer (score 0):

Create a phpinfo.php file with only this line of code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Upload the file to your server using an FTP Program (e.g FileZilla).
Look for the value of **memory_limit**.
If that value is lower than 64M, you should increase it to 92M (or 128M).
According to the WordPress documentation, here are some ways to change this:
Increase the amount of memory a PHP script may consume.

**Note:** If using a shared hosting service, you may need to ask your host to increase the limit.

1. Increase the memory limit setting in php.ini (e.g. memory_limit = 128M ;).
2. Increase the memory limit via .htaccess (e.g. php_value memory_limit 128M).
3. Increase the memory limit via wp-config.php (e.g. define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128MB');)

Check if it works.