# How to add jQuery code into HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(".icon-bg").click(function () {
    $(".btn").toggleClass("active");
    $(".icon-bg").toggleClass("active");
    $(".container").toggleClass("active");
    $(".box-upload").toggleClass("active");
    $(".box-caption").toggleClass("active");
    $(".box-tags").toggleClass("active");
    $(".private").toggleClass("active");
    $(".set-time-limit").toggleClass("active");
    $(".button").toggleClass("active");
});

$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".button-overlay").toggleClass("active");
});

$(".iconmelon").click(function () {
    $(".box-upload-ing").toggleClass("active");
    $(".iconmelon-loaded").toggleClass("active");
});

$(".private").click(function () {
    $(".private-overlay").addClass("active");
    $(".private-overlay-wave").addClass("active");
});
```

Can anyone help? It's for an upload function I found at http://codepen.io/iremlopsum/pen/YPWPap.
Trying to get it into my website

Comment: This is Jquery not Javascript!

Comment: I'm quite confused. If you just want to add it: put it in a file, and link to that JS-file in your html? If you don't know how to do that, I suggest you have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).
Also, check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Before copy paste this code, does you page have the elements that is matching the selectors in this code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106864/linking-jquery-in-html

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1) Best practice is to make new javascript file like my.js. Make this file into your js folder in root directory -> js/my.js .
2) In my.js file add your code inside of $(document).ready(function(){}) scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon-bg").click(function () {
        $(".btn").toggleClass("active");
        $(".icon-bg").toggleClass("active");
        $(".container").toggleClass("active");
        $(".box-upload").toggleClass("active");
        $(".box-caption").toggleClass("active");
        $(".box-tags").toggleClass("active");
        $(".private").toggleClass("active");
        $(".set-time-limit").toggleClass("active");
        $(".button").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".button").click(function () {
        $(".button-overlay").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".iconmelon").click(function () {
        $(".box-upload-ing").toggleClass("active");
        $(".iconmelon-loaded").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".private").click(function () {
        $(".private-overlay").addClass("active");
        $(".private-overlay-wave").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

3) add your new js file into your html

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/my.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: its even better to download the jquery file and load it locally from your server and not from google

Comment: @Asara why is this better? The way I understood is that the use of a CDN can greatly improve performance

Comment: Be careful copying the final code block; It is not the latest version now

Answer (score 27):

Before the closing `body` tag add this (reference to jQuery library). Other hosted libraries can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/?csw=1)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this

```
<script>
  //paste your code here
</script>
```

It should look something like this

```
<body>
 ........
 ........
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script> Your code </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend to call the script like this

```
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/my.js"></script>
</body>
```

The js and css files must be treat differently

> ***Put `jquery` as the first before other `JS scripts` at the bottom of `<BODY>` tag***

- The problem caused is that they block parallel downloads. The `HTTP/1.1 specification` suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname.
- So select 2 (two) most important scripts on your page like analytic and pixel script on the `<head>` tags and let the rest including the `jquery` to be called on the bottom `<body>` tag.

> ***Put `CSS style` on top of `<HEAD>` tag after the other more priority tags***

- Moving style sheets to the document `HEAD` makes pages appear to be loading faster. This is because putting style sheets in the `HEAD` allows the page to render progressively.
- So for `css` sheets, it is better to put them all on the `<head>` tag but let the style that shall be immediately rendered to be put in `<style>` tags inside `<HEAD>` and the rest in `<body>`.

You may also find other suggestion when you test your page like on [*Google PageSpeed Insight*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29488825/4058484)

Answer (score 6):

for latest Jquery. Simply:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a file for the jquery eg uploadfuntion.js.
2. Save that file in the same folder as website or in subfolder.
3. In `head` section of your html page paste: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and then the reference to your script eg: `<script src="uploadfuntion.js"> </script>`

4.Lastly you should ensure there are elements that match the selectors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you embedd the jQuery library into your page by adding the below
shown line into your `<head>` block:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your (first) post. This answer does not give any context. How does this solve any of the issues that still exist in this thread?