# javascript not working, to show and hide an element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have written some javascript code to hide and element based on id inside php, but it is not working

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['sign_up_btn'])){
        echo '
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#first").hide();
            $("#second").show();
            });

        </script>

        ';
    }
    ?>
```

I'm including jquery library like this in the tag above the closing body tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I solved it by referencing my jquery library before the echo... Thanks David

Comment: did you include jQuery library?  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796169/how-to-add-jquery-code-into-html-page)

Comment: Why is it just not being set with PHP directly on the elements?

Comment: Do you insert/echo your JS _before_ or _after_ the jQuery library is referenced?

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: i inserted the echo before the jquery library was referenced

Comment: That's the reason why it doesn't work. If the browser parses the HTML you generate, he _first_ encounters your own JS code (the one you `echo`), but at that point he does not know jQuery because it isn't referenced. Try loading jQuery inside the `<head>`. If the Error(s) persist/it does not work, then it's something else.

Comment: i solved it @David

Comment: `<div id="first" class="<?php echo isset($_POST['sign_up_btn']) ? ' hidden' : 'active' ?>"></div>`