# expiration not specified file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://www.mysite.ru/images/b1.gif (expiration not specified)
How to specify the expiration of files?
i did so , create .htaccess roots. And add 
install cache on 1 week

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #ExpiresDefault "access plus 608 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/.gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/.jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/.png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
   </IfModule>
```

what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "." from the extensions. In other words, use image/gif, image/jpeg and image/png. More information is [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html)

Comment: thanks for reply , i did so <IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 week"
</IfModule> but it did not help

Comment: Exactly where you are checking it?

Comment: After making any changes, wait for atleast 30 seconds and then check. Also take a look at the solutions provided on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878427/leverage-browser-caching-how-on-apache-or-htaccess)

Comment: I used ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A86400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
<FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch> wait 30 seconds , but nothing has happened as 78/100 and remains

Comment: Is this problem occurring for only GIF files?

Comment: http://www.woodfun.ru/images/wapkaRight.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://www.woodfun.ru/ntsaveforms.js (expiration not specified)

Comment: Have you added
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
      ModPagespeed on
       ModPagespeedDomain YOUR-DOMAIN</IfModule>
before this "expires.c" code